# JQuery UI AutoComplete AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I am trying to create a search field that autocompletes with suggestions from a database using an ajax call. Upon selecting an item, I would like for it to update the search field.  Currently when I type something into this textbox, it returns an empty selection. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the code, updated with recommended changes, however now I am getting the empty list.

```
function autoCompleteCheckRun() {
$('#autocompleteCR')
          .autocomplete({
              minLength: 0,
              source: function (request, response) {
                  $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                      url: './PayInvoicesWS.asmx/GetCheckRun',
                      data: "{'description':'" + document.getElementById('autocompleteCR').value + "'}",
                      dataType: "json",
                      success: function (data) {
                          var rows = autocompleteJSONParseCode(data);
                          response(rows);
                      },
                      error: function (result) {
                          alert("Error");
                      },
                      select: function (event, ui) {
                          var checkRunData = $("#CheckRunDescription");
                          var checkRunID = $("#CheckRunID");
                          checkRunData.val(ui.item.label);
                          checkRunID.val(ui.item.value);


                      }
                  });
              }
          });
 }

function autocompleteJSONParseCode(data) {
    var rows = new Array();
    var rowData = null;
    for (var i = 0, dataLength = data.d.length; i < dataLength; i++) {
        rowData = data.d[i];
        // alert(rowData.term2+":"+rowData.term1);//uncomment to see data as it parses
        rows[i] = {
            value: rowData.CheckRunID,
            label: rowData.Description
        };
    }

    return rows;
}

div class="ui-widget">
                        <label for="autocompleteCR" id="checkRunLabel">Check Run Lookup:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="autocompleteCR" />
                    </div>
```

[image: example]

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve on selecting the item from autocomplete suggestion? Isn't it obvious when you ll select an item, it will automatically be filled with the selected item? can you explain your question better?

Comment: I want it to populate another textbox, which I will then use its value as a parameter for another ajax call that grabs items from a particular database table.

Comment: Check the updated fiddle in my answer. I have made changes to fill value in another box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have misplaced `select` function. Move it out from `source` function and place parallel to the `source` function.

```
$('#autocompleteCR')
          .autocomplete({
              minLength: 0,
              source: function (request, response) {
                  $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                      url: './PayInvoicesWS.asmx/GetCheckRun',
                      data: "{'description':'" + document.getElementById('autocompleteCR').value + "'}",
                      dataType: "json",
                      success: function (data) {
                          var rows = autocompleteJSONParseCode(data);
                          response(rows);
                      },
                      error: function (result) {
                          alert("Error");
                      }
                  });
              },
              select: function (event, ui) {
                          var checkRunData = $("#CheckRunDescription");
                          var checkRunID = $("#CheckRunID");
                          checkRunData.val(ui.item.label);
                          checkRunID.val(ui.item.value);


              }
          });
```

I have made a working example for what you are looking for:

https://jsfiddle.net/gschambial/d0g3dLvu/19/

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags,
  select: function(event, ui) {
            alert('Label is :' + ui.item.label + ' and Value is : ' +ui.item.value);
    }
});
```

Change

```
function(el) {
return {
     CheckRunID: el.CheckRunID,
     Description: el.Description
     };
}));
```

To

```
function(el) {
return {
     value: el.CheckRunID,
     label: el.Description
     };
}));
```

and instead of

```
checkRunData.val(ui.item.CheckRunID + ui.item.Description);
```

use

```
checkRunData.val(ui.item.label + ui.item.value);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reponse.  I made the recommended changes.  When I enter text into the field it does hit the server side code and returns the list of objects I'm looking for. However, the autocomplete returns an empty selection, which I've provided in the original post. It's probably something to do with how I'm selecting the dom elements.

Comment: Can you try `console.log(ui.item.value)` and tell me what's shown on developer console?

Comment: Also try after removing, `event.preventDefault();` from your code.

Comment: Would you like me to add it on the select function?

Comment: I also put a breakpoint on the return part of the success function, and el shows the objects in an array.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in the selcet function and inspected what is there in the `ui` object?

Comment: Ok so I updated my code and i'm now returning a list, it allows me to select an item in the list, and the value shows in the search field.  However when I breakpoint on the checkRunID.val(ui.item.value), it never hits it.

Comment: In the screenshot you added, you are typing check but there is no auto complete list being shown below. Your select function wil be invoked only when you select an item from auto complete list.

Comment: Are you able to view auto complete list when you start typing in your textbox?

Comment: I just updated the picture to show what I'm returning.  When I select one of those, it puts the value into the textfield. I also would like to add the description part into another textbox with the id CheckRunDescription.  Still not hitting the select function on a breakpoint though.

Comment: You have misplaced `select` function. MOve it out from `source` function. I have updated the answer. Check it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what got it to work: Assigning a variable to data.d inside the success function of the ajax call.  Also @gschambial's suggestion regarding where I had my select function.  Originally it was inside of the source function, which once I moved outside of it, I was able to assign the values from the list to dom elements.

```
function autoCompleteCheckRun() {
$('#autocompleteCR')
          .autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: './PayInvoicesWS.asmx/GetCheckRun',
                data: "{'description':'" + document.getElementById('autocompleteCR').value + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    var el = data.d;
                    response($.map(el,
                        function(el) {
                            return {
                                label: el.Description,
                                value: el.CheckRunID
                            }
                        }));
                },
                error: function(result) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
             });
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                  $("#CheckRunDescription").val(ui.item.label);
                  $("#CheckRunID").val(ui.item.value);
                event.stopPropagation();
            }

          });
      }
```

The View:

```
 <div class="ui-widget">
                        <label for="autocompleteCR" id="checkRunLabel">Check Run Lookup:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="autocompleteCR" />
                    </div>
<div class="divTableCell">
                <label for="CheckRunDescription" id="checkRunDescriptionLabel">Description:</label>
                <input type="text" id="CheckRunDescription" style="width: 270px;" />
            </div>
```